# How to implement Google Maps API v2 to Android Application without it crashing?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make an application as a school project and I MUST implement Google Maps. I am fairly new to Android coding and now little of Java. So far I created this application using Google Maps API v2, I obtained a key, I added all the permissions and code in the manifest, I added the default Google example code to make a map simply appear but I get a crash and lots of errors when running the application. I also added existing code and set it to project library, I set target and compile with to be specifically with the API's. I keep "banging my head" trying to get this to work. I saw other questions have similar problems but resolved with something I already have completed.
Since I'm having troubles adding code by text, I hope you guys can understand I used exactly what Google posted as their tutorial. I can't do images due to my rep.

Comment: Use LogCat (e.g., in DDMS) to examine the stack trace associated with your error. If you cannot understand the stack trace, post it along with any relevant source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this thanks to newbostonforums and I am adding my findings for anyone else seeking help. You need to add google-play-services_lib to your project.

Right click IMPORT
Android->Existing Code->(SDK/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib)

Right click on project. Properties->Android->Library-ADD->(SDK/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Once you added the folder it will be "linked" with the project.

In JAVA you must add

MAKE SURE YOU IMPORT ALL RED UNDERLINED.

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

Then your XML can be at your choosing but it must include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
// POSSIBLY OPTIONAL
android:id="@+id/map"
```

You may replace android:name with class but I don't know the difference. I believe they both work.

However there are many ways to make it work and I am somewhat changing this method.