# How to implement Google step by step navigation in android map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google map version V2 to display map in my app . I want to implement Google step by step navigation in my app . Please help me by sharing some ideas .

Comment: Those who put negative voting . Please share the reason for negative votting .

Comment: Sam how you implement google navigation in your app?

Answer (score 0):

See below link:-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

[How to implement Google Maps API v2 to Android Application without it crashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015207/how-to-implement-google-maps-api-v2-to-android-application-without-it-crashing)